# Finding valves to turn off for water line using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-water-utilities

I am wondering if there is a tool for ArcMap that can do what I am about to describe. It might be in network analysis but I am not sure. I have used water gems but it does not do what I want it to do.

Lets say I have a network of water lines.  These water lines all have valves.  Now, lets say I have to fix a certain spot on one line and I need to know all the valves that needs to be turned off to shut off the water to that line so the men can work on that line.

How can this be done?

What would be nice is that I am able to chose the line and point where the breakage is located and it tells me all the valves that need to be turn off to stop the water.

Any idea if there is a tool like that already or even how could we do this with ArcObjects of Python?

Answer (score 5):

[ArcGIS for Water Utilities](http://solutions.arcgis.com/utilities/water/help/network-editing/) is a free add-on from Esri for ArcGIS Desktop that offers network tracing including Valve Isolation.

The Valve Isolation tool traces your network from a specified point (eg your pipe fix location) and determines which valves should be shut off to isolate that point, and will also tell you which other features (lines, connections, valves) would now be without water.

Your water network will need to be in a Geometric Network to allow tracing to occur.

Comment: That sounds Awesome! I will give that a try tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: If your water data is not currently in a geometric network, it can be a complicated task to convert particularly if the data is not well connected (valves snapped to pipes, etc.)
Here is a good blog post on creating a water geometric network - [Geometric networks for water utilities](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/11/17/geometric-networks-for-water-utilities/)

Comment: Thank you Midavalo. Great information. Also, I will have to clean the original network up so I can convert it to a proper geometric network. A geometric network is what I was looking to achieve because it allow me to do everything I am needing to accomplish. Thank you for the information and help. I appreciate your time and knowledge.