# Performing water valve isolation trace using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, geometric-network, trace, arcfm

The utility that I am working with for a couple of weeks has access to the [ArcFM Water Valve Isolation tool](http://resources.arcfmsolution.com/10.1/Appendix/Water_Valve_Isolation.html) which enables them to point from ArcMap at a location on their SDE Geometric Network and be shown the water valves with NORMALPOSITION OPEN that would need to be CLOSED to isolate that part of the network in the event of a pipe burst.

I am not strong on ArcFM, but I what I am hoping to do from ArcPy (with ArcFM licensing available) is to take a list of 2500 locations on the geometric network, and have an isolation trace return a list of all valves that any of these identify as being used as potential isolation valves from bursts at those locations.

Doing 2500 isolation traces from ArcPy should be easy if I can do one isolation trace from ArcPy.

Is it possible to perform an isolation trace from ArcPy with ArcGIS 10.2.1.01 (Standard level license; with or without ArcFM)?

From [@Midavalo's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/176272/115) to [Finding valves to turn off for water line using ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176262) I was hoping that ArcGIS for Water Utilities download might offer some suitable Python code but when I downloaded it the Valve Isolation tool seems to use ArcObjects instead.

I have also been looking at the [Trace Geometric Network](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000015r000000) tool which is ArcPy accessible but does not offer the option of an isolation trace.

Comment: You are correct, the OOTB trace tools won't do an isolation trace - there is a lot of configuration required first.  The ArcGIS for water utilities tools are fantastic, but yes they do require toolbar or ArcObjects.  Personally I'm not a fan of ArcFM isolation traces - they do not give accurate results (which I have told Schneider in the past) and we elected to not even purchase ArcFM due to this major issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't comment on the ArcFM component of your question, but if you want a sample that does Valve Isolation off a geometric network, I just uploaded what I have to [arcgis.com](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=e58a0d44fe0c4b68868384dc748d5185)

I'm not the original author, it was passed down to me (thus I make no claims on being an expert in this area, nor to how authoritative it is). You can turn the model into a script. The basic workflow is:

- snap your input point to the line
- perform a trace on the network
- select all the relevant valves
- filter that list (there is a script tool inside the model that uses a DA cursor to filter)

Comment: This sounds exactly like what I need.  However, I made the mistake of not specifying the version of ArcGIS that I am using.  It is 10.2.1.01 and your package appears to have been created using 10.5.x and although it unpacks with 10.2.1.01 none of the toolboxes show their tools in the Catalog window.  Is there any chance that you can provide another geoprocessing package that can be used with 10.2.x?

Comment: I went home to grab my laptop with 10.5.1 and the tools are visible there with no problem.  A 10.2 version might still be useful but I'm confident that I can now access what I need.