# Unzipping geoprocessing package (GPK) file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing-package

I was under the impression that all ArcGIS package files could have their contents examined and potentially used by renaming them to `*.zip` and unzipping them.

This impression is supported for map package (`*.mpk`) files by [@KHibma's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/137692/115) to [Opening MPK file without ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137689/opening-mpk-file-without-arcgis-desktop) and I thought I had used it succesfully on geoprocessing package (`*.gpk`) files in the past.

However, today I am unable to use a [tool within a `*.gpk`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/260499/115) which I think is because it was created using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.x when I am using 10.2.1.01. When I rename this `*.gpk` as `*.zip` and try to examine it in Windows Explorer I get:

> *Compressed (zipped) Folders Error*
>
> Windows cannot open the folder
>
> The Compressed (zipped) Folder ...`.zip` is invalid.

[image]

Is it possible to unzip a geoprocessing package (`*.gpk`) file to see whether it may contain some useful ArcPy code when that `*.gpk` cannot be unpacked to provide a usable toolbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try .7z instead of .zip. the .*pk uses 7zip encoding and not zip.

Source - open a .*pk file in notepad++ or something and you will see the first characters are 7z. That is a 7zip header. Read more about the 7z file encoding here: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/BJOERN/Compress-Deflate7-1.0/7zip/DOC/7zFormat.txt

Zip file headers start with a PK. Read more about zip encoding here:  https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT

Comment: You may well be right.  Unfortunately, I'm in a locked down environment and installing 7-zip to test may be challenging.

Comment: Use the version from portableapp.com.